# onSupportNavigateUp not called when no Actionbar is used

Tags: android

I am using a toolbar but without an Actionbar or a AppBarLayout. Pressing on the Up (Back) button arrow in the top left corner does not trigger the onSupportNavigateUp method. One Stackoverflow ticket indicates that if you override onOptionsItemSelected, it will not be called. So I removed onOptionsItemSelected. But that didn't help. Here's my code:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: did your override the method?

Answer (score 1):

In onCreateOptionsMenu I was returning false, which prevents onSupportNavigateUp from being called. I returned false because I needed to hide the overflow menu (3 dots in the upper right corner). Looks like I'll have to find another way of hiding that menu.